# Lazy loading in jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I don't have much knowledge of jQuery. I do one task in android/blackberry: [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) (meaning that if I am getting 1000 data I only want to show some content). When I scroll to the end of the content that is displayed the next packet of data is then loaded. Is there a function or possibility for this in jQuery and jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Here is a plugin. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload Did you even try Google?

Comment: yes I found this but it is not much usefull..

Comment: is there any example ..can you post any example on fiddle

Comment: hm.. why you do not use https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll ?

Comment: Actually can you please make example on fiddle..

Comment: @user944513 I can't help but feel that you are unwilling to do any work yourself and that you are expecting us to do it all for you.  This site is geared towards answers to specific problems and not as a means to get your work / homework done for you.

Comment: Yes it is possible download source 1)https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview